# The method doesn't want to enter in for loo

Tags: python

```
def getAvg(channel_id):
    videos = v_db.find({'channelId':channel_id})
    if len(list(videos)) > 1:
        total_days=0
        first = True
        print('here-1')
        for video in list(videos):
            data = video['publishedAt']
            print('here-2')
            if first:
                old_date = formatDate(data)
                first = False
                continue
            else:
                current_date = formatDate(data)
                days = abs((old_date - current_date).days)
            old_date = current_date
            total_days += int(days)
        avg = total_days / len(list(videos))
        avg = round(avg, 0)
    else:
        avg = None
    return avg
```

What's the problem with this damn loop? I don't understand why the method doesn't acces the loop. I tried to make videos a list because cursor type can't be parsed. If I'm running this for loop alone, without the if statement above, it works.

```
videos = v_db.find({'channelId':'UC8PQ5xjJNp6wgpF9GXmlkvw'})
for video in list(videos):
    print('here-2')
```

Comment: There is an indentation problem on the code posted. Please verify it and check if it matches the actual code. Indentation means a lot for Python, this can help people understanding

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  What is `v_db`?  Have you verified that `list(videos)` is what you expect?  And what should happen if the length of that list is 1?

Comment: v_db is a collection from MongoDB. @AlexanderSantos The identation is proper, the code was pasted wrong.

Comment: @ScottHunter I have the else state where set the avg = None. If len(llist(videos)) is not greater than 1, then is lower or equals, right?

Comment: It seems correct, is it printing this statement: `print('here-1')`  ?

Comment: does using `videos.count_documents()` or `videos.count()` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`videos` is an iterable, and you can only iterate over it once. You exhaust it when you do `if len(list(videos)) > 1:`, so there's nothing left when you try to do `for video in list(videos):`.

The solution is to put the list in a variable.

```
def getAvg(channel_id):
    videos = list(v_db.find({'channelId':channel_id}))
    if len(videos) > 0:
        total_days=0
        first = True
        print('here-1')
        for video in videos:
            data = video['publishedAt']
            print('here-2')
            if first:
                old_date = formatDate(data)
                first = False
                continue
            else:
                current_date = formatDate(data)
                days = abs((old_date - current_date).days)
            old_date = current_date
            total_days += int(days)
        avg = total_days / len(videos)
        avg = round(avg, 0)
    else:
        avg = None
    return avg
```

Also, you should test `len > 0`. There's no problem with calculating the average of 1 video.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the solution. I don't want channels with just one video, that's why I used len > 1.